# Access denied - EMR Presto - File Based Authorization

Tags: hive, amazon-emr, presto, trino

I have a strange issue while querying from Presto (AWS EMR). I was using Presto 0.194 and everything was ok, after I upgraded to 0.224, I cannot run my queries. I'm using LDAP authentication for presto and also file base authorization for Hive using a authorization.json file. I'm using the same json file which was working fine in the old version. Any help would highly appreciated.

Error:
Query 20191005_104119_00006_3snge failed: Access Denied: View owner 'username' cannot create view that selects from ...

config.propertis:

```
coordinator=true
node-scheduler.include-coordinator=false
discovery.uri=http://IP.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal:8889
http-server.threads.max=500
discovery-server.enabled=true
sink.max-buffer-size=1GB
query.max-memory=30GB
query.max-memory-per-node=6532645258B
query.max-total-memory-per-node=7839174309B
query.max-history=40
query.min-expire-age=30m
http-server.http.port=8889
http-server.log.path=/var/log/presto/http-request.log
http-server.log.max-size=67108864B
http-server.log.max-history=5
log.max-size=268435456B
log.max-history=5
query.execution-policy=phased
optimizer.dictionary-aggregation=true
optimizer.optimize-metadata-queries=true
colocated-joins-enabled=true
http-server.authentication.type=PASSWORD
http-server.https.enabled=true
http-server.https.port=9443
http-server.https.keystore.path=/etc/presto/presto_keystore.jks
http-server.https.keystore.key=passw0rd
node-scheduler.max-splits-per-node=125
optimizer.use-mark-distinct=false
```

hive.properties:

```
hive.metastore-refresh-interval=1m
connector.name=hive-hadoop2
hive.metastore.uri=thrift://ip-10-0-2-141.ap-southeast- 
1.compute.internal:9083
hive.metastore-cache-ttl=20m
hive.config.resources=/etc/hadoop/conf/core- 
site.xml,/etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml
hive.non-managed-table-writes-enabled = true
hive.s3-file-system-type = EMRFS
hive.hdfs.authentication.type = NONE
hive.hdfs.impersonation.enabled = true
hive.orc.bloom-filters.enabled=true
hive.recursive-directories=true
hive.s3select-pushdown.enabled=true
hive.security=file
security.config-file=/etc/presto/conf.dist/authorization.json
```

authorization.json:

```
{
"schemas": [
{
  "user": "prestoSA",
  "owner": true
},
{
  "user": "marketing_jack",
  "owner": true
},
{
  "user": "system-apiquery",
  "owner": true
},
{
  "user": "redash",
  "owner": true
},
{
  "user": "system_.*",
  "schema": "prestosync_.*",
  "owner": true
},
{
  "user": "system_.*",
  "schema": "views_.*",
  "owner": true
},
{
  "user": "system_.*",
  "schema": "raw_.*",
  "owner": true
}
],
"tables": [
{
  "user": "prestoSA",
  "privileges": [
    "SELECT",
    "INSERT",
    "DELETE",
    "OWNERSHIP"
  ]
},
{
  "user": "redash",
  "privileges": [
    "SELECT"
  ]
},
{
  "schema": "raw_.*",
  "user": "system_.*",
  "privileges": [
    "SELECT",
    "INSERT",
    "DELETE",
    "OWNERSHIP"
  ]
},
{
  "schema": "production_.*",
  "user": "system_.*",
  "privileges": [
    "SELECT",
    "INSERT",
    "DELETE",
    "OWNERSHIP"
  ]
},
{
  "schema": "prestosync_.*",
  "user": "system_.*",
  "privileges": [
    "SELECT",
    "INSERT",
    "DELETE",
    "OWNERSHIP"
  ]
},
{
  "schema": "views_.*",
  "user": "system_.*",
  "privileges": [
    "SELECT",
    "INSERT",
    "DELETE",
    "OWNERSHIP"
  ]
},
{
  "schema": ".*dev",
  "user": "developer_.*",
  "privileges": [
    "SELECT"
  ]
},
{
  "schema": "raw_rin",
  "user": "developer_.*",
  "privileges": [
    "SELECT"
  ]
},
{
  "schema": ".*prod",
  "user": "developer_.*",
  "privileges": [
    "SELECT"
  ]
},
{
  "schema": "views_development_.*",
  "user": "marketing_.*",
  "privileges": [
    "SELECT"
  ]
},
{
  "schema": "views_prod",
  "user": "marketing_.*",
  "privileges": [
    "SELECT"
  ]
},
{
  "schema": "views_dev",
  "user": "sales_.*",
  "privileges": [
    "SELECT"
  ]
},
{
  "schema": "views_prod",
  "user": "sales_.*",
  "privileges": [
    "SELECT"
  ]
},
{
  "schema": "emr59_prod",
  "user": "marketing_.*",
  "privileges": [
    "SELECT"
  ]
},
{
  "schema": "views_dev",
  "user": "management_.*",
  "privileges": [
    "SELECT"
  ]
},
{
  "schema": "views_prod",
  "user": "management_.*",
  "privileges": [
    "SELECT"
  ]
},
{
  "schema": "views_dev",
  "user": "management_.*",
  "privileges": [
    "SELECT"
  ]
},
{
  "schema": "views_prod",
  "user": "management_.*",
  "privileges": [
    "SELECT"
  ]
}
]
}
```

acceess-control.properties:

```
access-control.name=file
security.config-file=/etc/presto/conf.dist/rules.json
```

rules.json:

```
{
"catalogs": [
 {
  "user": "system_.*",
  "catalog": "(mysql|system)",
  "allow": true
},
{
  "user": "prestoSA",
  "catalog": "(mysql|system)",
  "allow": true
},
{
  "user": "redash",
  "catalog": "(mysql|system)",
  "allow": true
},
{
  "user": "developer_.*",
  "catalog": "(mysql|hive)",
  "allow": true
},
{
  "catalog": "hive",
  "allow": true
},
{
  "catalog": "system",
  "allow": false
}
]
}
```

Comment: You didn't upload any authorization.json file, config file just error than how can I help you?

Comment: @Lamanus Thanks for the reply. I added the configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Error: Query 20191005_104119_00006_3snge failed: Access Denied: View owner 'username' cannot create view that selects from ...

This means that `username` does not have `GRANT_SELECT` privilege on a particular table or tables.

The particular change that affects you went in in 0.199 release:
https://github.com/prestosql/presto/commit/6ed1ed88083baef1d29171364297631962adf05d
This was a bug fix (creating view should require different privileges), so it is intentional (although inconvenient) that the change did not maintain backward compatibility.

BTW
For one-time troubleshooting-style questions which are unlikely to be beneficial for SO community I recommend using `#troubleshooting` channel on [Presto Community Slack](https://prestosql.io/slack.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Piotr!

1. It seems that I need an invitation to join the Slack workspace. (ahmokhtari@gmail.com)
2. As I mentioned in my question, we're using file authorization method for the hive and all of the privileges are available in the authorization.json file. Same file with same content is working in the older version.

Comment: @ahmokhtari re 1: https://prestosql.io/slack.html has a sign-up link, but I've sent you a personal invite. Re 2: I added reference to the commit which changed the behavior requiring you to update the configuration.